# Unable to statically link executable with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking

I am trying to compile and link a static executable such that it can run on different systems without making any assumptions about which versions of different libraries is installed and so on.

Following CMake documentation I am adding `target_link_libraries(target -static)` to my CMakeLists.txt. Unfortunatly I dont see a way of probing whether this had any effect. But by inspecting the executable with `ldd executable`. I get the following output

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe29eb000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f54cbbb2000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f54cb829000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f54cb48b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f54cb09a000)
    /lib/ld64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f54cbdd1000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f54cae82000)
```

Which tells me that the executable indeed is linked with dynamic libraries (*.so). Does anyone have any advise for investigating this further? I really find this to be one of the disadvantages of CMake. At this point, the project is complex enough that it would really take a long time to do compilation and linking from the command line or make a Makefile system. But I really need to look at the actual flags passed to GCC to understand why this is happening.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to add `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! However, adding those flags: ``target_link_libraries(target -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`` makes no difference